# Picking 3 coins from 6 coins without replacement. What is probability of getting a nickel on a certain pick?

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with this problem: There is 1 nickel, 2 dimes, and 3 quarters in a cup. You pick 3, one at a time, without replacement. What is the probability of getting a nickel on the first pick? What is the probability of getting a nickel on the second pick? What is the probability of getting a nickel on the third pick?

My attempt: 
1+2+3=6
nickel on first pick: 1/6
nickel on second pick: 1/5
nickel on third pick: 1/4

However the back of the book says each pick has a 20/120=1/6 chance of being a nickel. How is this possible since the sample space decreases by 1 each pick because there is no replacement. I realize that 6*5*4=120 and that there are 20/120 outcomes with nickels. I also realize that if a nickel is chosen for for one of the three spots that it cannot be chosen for the other 2 spots but I still am not understanding.

Comment: Think you might have the wrong SE site... This isn't programming-related.

Comment: The nickel has a `1/6` chance of being in any particular position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
First pick:                             1/6
Second pick:       5/6 * 1/5 =  5/30  = 1/6
Third pick:  5/6 * 4/5 * 1/4 = 20/120 = 1/6
```

I agreed with you at first but then after a bit of thinking I figured out how they got their answer. If you read between the lines, you will see that it's not just about picking a nickel. It's also about NOT picking a nickel the first and/or second time.

In other words, if you want to draw a nickel on the third draw, then you must NOT draw it on the first try (5/6), NOT draw it on the second try (4/5), and then draw it on the third try (1/4).

P.S. This is the wrong forum, but I couldn't help but answering. Try [StackExchange's Math Forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/) next time.